# Alias in OData select statement

Tags: odata

Do you know if there is any equivalent function to the SQL **"as"** statement in OData?

I need to do something like:

```
$select=field1 as revenue
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update (February 2020)**

This request has been completed. Within OData, expressions can be given an alias within the [`$compute` query option](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.01/odata-v4.01-part2-url-conventions.html#sec_SystemQueryOptioncompute) or within [aggregations](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-data-aggregation-ext/v4.0/cs02/odata-data-aggregation-ext-v4.0-cs02.html#_Toc435016569).

**Original**

Something like this has been brought up to the OASIS committee ([request: "allow expressions in the *$select* query option"](https://tools.oasis-open.org/issues/browse/ODATA-9)), and the solution was to defer as a possible enhancement in future versions.

Comment: It appears that some or all of this has since been implemented. The link mentioned in this answer is marked as "fixed".