# Is it possible to use column alias in odata select?

Tags: select, odata, alias

I'm trying to get the data from a column with the name "contactName", and i want the results to show as "Name".
Is this possible in odata select?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alias in OData select statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20666056/alias-in-odata-select-statement)

Comment: I don't think so. I want the alias as in SQL, like "select contactName as Name". If you know how to do it without using aggregation or compute options, please let me know. In the example, they're using two numeric columns and returning the result as an alias, but i only want one column that returns a string value.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to bind your DBContext to a SQL View instead of the table.  In the SQL view create your Alias.